# jQuery-ui accordion not being rendered correctly on IE 7 (Refresh issues)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an accordion with two panels within a jQuery tab. Following this I have a jqGrid table. See below skeleton:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Tab-1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Tab-2">Tab2</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="Tab-1">
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="group">           
            <h3>Panel 1</h3>                   
                     <div>
                          // My stuff
                     </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">           
            <h3>Panel 2</h3>                   
                     <div>
                          // My stuff
                     </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end accordion -->
    <div id="jqGrid">
        @Html.Partial("../Grids/_MyjqGrid")
    </div>
</div> <!-- End First tab -->
<div id="Tab-2">
    // My stuff for tab-2
</div>
</div> <!-- end tabs -->
```

When I expand and colapse the panels continuously, sometimes the panel that is being collapsed disappears or simply its position is not updated (refresh). After a few seconds, when I move the mouse over it, it is refreshed and it is positioned correctly. As a result of it, as jqGrid is placed below, its position is not updated correctly (refreshed) after I move the mouse over. What's happening?

It is hapenning only in IE 7. In IE 8, 9 and 10 works perfectly. Any ideas?

I am using:

jquery-1.9.1.js 
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css

Comment: I've ran into the exact same issue, did you ever find a fix for this?